# Huge click discrepancy between adsense and google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, ads, adsense, publisher

I'm seeing a huge click discrepancy between adsense and GA reports. I am adding reports for the same time interval:

[image: GA report]
[image: Adsense Report]

I thought some of the clicks may be invalid but is this much discrepancy okay? It is also making the CTR extremely low since number of clicks are low.

Answer (score -2):

From documentation:

If you see significant discrepancies between the reports in your AdSense account and those in the AdSense section of Analytics, then please keep in mind these important points:

- AdSense reports in Analytics only track AdSense for content ad units, and do not include link units, search boxes, mobile ads, or any other AdSense products.
- Impressions from Matched content units are included in Google Analytics reports, but not in AdSense reports unless they have the Matched content metric family selected. Learn more about tracking the performance of Matched content units.
- You must include Analytics code on every webpage running AdSense for content ad units.

More info about why statistics differ between AdSense and Analytics here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6090783?hl=en